# I want to pass an image as a prop to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

The main problem is that this image is selected from the file explorer and I am using react-router.
`Add.js`
this is where you select the image

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./About";
import './styles/modal.css'
import firebase from "firebase";
require("firebase/firestore")
require("firebase/storage")



export default function Add(props) {
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

    const pickImage = (event) => {
        //console.log();
        setImage(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
        //console.log(image);
    }
    const toggle = () => {
        setModal(!modal);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Add</h1>
            <button onClick={toggle}>Add image</button>
            {modal ? (
                <div className="modal-bg">
                    <div className="modal">
                        <img src={image} style={{ width: '60%', height: '60%' }} className="ex-img" />
                        <br /><br />
                        <label htmlFor="fie" className="gcoo btn-default">+ File
                            <input id="fie" type="file" onChange={pickImage} className="file-pick" />
                        </label>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div className="bottom-buttons">
                            <Link to="/about">
                                <button className="save">Save</button>
                            </Link>
                            <button onClick={() => setModal(false)} className="closse">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : null}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am using firebase but not in this file so you can ignore this.
`MainRoutes.js`
this is where all the routes and pages are.

```
import { Route } from "react-router";
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import ImageDisplay from "./components/ImageDisplay";
import Add from './components/Add';

export default function MainRoute(props) {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/about" component={() => <ImageDisplay />} />
            <Route exact path="/add" component={() => <Add />} /> 
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

finally this file `ImageDisplay.js` is where the image should be displayed
I dont have much on this file because i dont know how to put in any images.
I have tried props but whenever i imported the Imagedisplay it always showed the content on it and i dont want anything from image display. I only want to send an image over there.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

function ImageDisplay(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>image</h1>
            <div>
                <img />
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default ImageDisplay;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are not *reloading* the page when moving between the two routes, since this will remove all state.

To share state between the two components you would need to store the state in the parent, and pass it to the children.

Add:

```
export default function Add(props) {
    const pickImage = (event) => {
        props.setImage(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
    }

    // The rest of your function
}
```

And in your parent:

```
export default function MainRoute(props) {
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/about" component={() => <ImageDisplay image={image} />} />
            <Route exact path="/add" component={() => <Add setImage={setImage} />} /> 
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

You can now access the `image` prop in your imageDisplay.

```
function ImageDisplay(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>image</h1>
            <div>
                <img src={props.image} />
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```